# Bootstrap button groups + Radio Buttons, checked value is not working in Firefox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website using bootstrap and using button groups overlaid on top of radio buttons to load certain content based on which radio button is checked . I check value attribute in radio buttons to decide which content to load (using jQuery). Here is JSFiddle for the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/F2Kr3/1/

If you run this in Chrome then you get radio button values in alert prompts.

If you run this in Firefox then you get "undefined" in alert prompts.

Any reason, why FF is behaving this way or I have done something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this works for Chrome is that it triggers the `click` event down to the `input:radio` level, while Firefox doesn't have this kind of behavior.

As far as I know, Bootstrap doesn't handle this functionality between buttons and nested input radio buttons. So you'll have to set the checked attribute of the `input:radio` buttons on click of a Bootstrap styled `button`.

```
$('div.btn-group .btn').click(function(){
  $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
  alert($('input[name=radio-btn-ctrl]:checked').val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3prAu/1/